# get veehd url in bash/python?

Tags: bash

Can anybody figure out how to get the *.avi* URL of a veehd[dot]com video, by providing the page of the video in a script? It can be BASH, or Python, or common programs in Ubuntu.

They make you install a extension, and I've tried looking at the code but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you link to the extension? And any reason you want to do this in BASH only? A scripting language like Python or Ruby would make this trivial.

Comment: Well, they host the .crx file, but I've zipped the extension's contents here: http://www.mediafire.com/?ccyph46bs46vui5
Oh.. It doesn't *have* to be bash, but I use bash to automate downloading.  It can be Python, or probably ruby too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
URL=$1 # page with the video
FRAME=`wget -q -O - $URL | sed -n -e '/playeriframe.*do=d/{s/.*src : "//;s/".*//p;q}'`
STREAM=`wget -q -O - http://veehd.com$FRAME | sed -n -e '/<a/{s/.*href="//;s/".*//p;q}'`
echo $STREAM
```

Comment: Alright, I just tried that.  But all I get for an output is "http://www.google.com/chrome"

Comment: What URL do you supply as first parameter? I use it like this: `./veehd.sh 'http://veehd.com/video/6666666_The-Title-Of-The-Video'` and the result is `http://v33.veehd.com/dl/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/DDDDDDDDDD/DDDD.DDDDDDD.avi&b=DDD` where `X` are all hex digits and `D` are decimal digits.

Comment: ohh, yes, I was using the same format of url.. but I tried a random video, [instead of a specific one I was trying to get the URL of] and it works.  I tried that other one again, and it still outputs "google.com/chrome"...haha, weird, but it's still a valid video. anyway, I have added vee.sh to my ~/bin/ folder, thanks.  btw, where did you find this script? I googled a lot b4 asking this, and never found anything.

Comment: No wonder you didn't find this one - I wrote it specifically as answer to your question. That's what SO is for :)

Comment: ahh I kinda suspected so..but I believed I used CURL and tried to grep for .avi in the past, even the frame [I sorta remember their being a frame now that I think of it], but found nothing.. wonder how I missed it.  I did know they make you get a plugin just for the sake of having one for it to work. [all it does is add a <meta> tag to say "Plugin installed" to the page's code].. but thanks again